# JAVA: saving a string encoded into a number (not parseInt)

Tags: java, string, io, simulator

I'm wondering if there is a way to convert a string into a number to be stored (not parseInt).

Say, I have a user input a string `"Some characters here and 12234"`, is there a way to convert this to a specific number? That later on, that number can be interpreted and print back out as the same string?

I thought about implementing it as ASCII characters, but ASCII characters require 1 byte for each characters, but my number is only 16-bit long (short).

For more information, I'm implementing a basic computer simulator and I'm trying to implement simple I/O instructions. The numbers will be stored into a register that is 16-bit in size.
The problem is that the instruction format is fixed, which is "IN reg, device" or "OUT reg, device". If I use ASCII, the reg can only hold 2 characters at a time, then I will have to save that into our virtual memory, but there is no spot in the instruction to indicate where in memory it will be.

Comment: *then I will have to save that into our virtual memory, but there is no spot in the instruction to indicate where in memory it will be.*   That's the job of the "input a string" function that uses the IN instruction, not the job of the IN instruction.  Plenty of actual computers manage to read strings despite only having "read a character into a register" in the instruction set.  Your simulated computer can work the same way.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your feedback. I'm just having trouble finding the right keywords to look things up. I can't seem to find the right resources since most of what I found are more high level languages, and this is more machine code. Is there any way you can help point me to where I can find these information? Or even just what the right keywords are?

Comment: This is a basic programming exercise: given a way to read a single character at a time, assemble an integer value from a sequence of characters.  The fundamental step is that for each digit value you get (0 to 9 for decimal input), multiply the number-so-far by 10 (if you want decimal input) and add the new digit value.  It doesn't matter if your read-a-character routine is a machine instruction or some "readchar" library routine, the algorithm is the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is mathematically impossible, by way of the pigeonhole principle. Imagine you're in a room with 3 lightswitches in it, that do nothing. You get to walk in, fiddle with the switches, and you must walk out again. You can't leave anything, you can't mess with anything else.

Later I enter the same room, and I get to look at the switches, that's all.

We can communicate only 8 different things, because I can fully enumerate each and every situation you can possibly create: DDD, DDU, DUD, DUU, UDD, UDU, UUD, and UUU. That's 8.

2 bytes is the same, except, its 16 lightswitches, not 3. You can thus communicate 65536 different states (2^16).

There are way more than 65536 strings of length 30 or so, which the message "Some characters here and 12234" is long. Given that you have to 'compress' it down to 65536 different unique states, there can only be 65536 different strings that you can possibly represent. You're free to choose whatever 65536 different strings you want, but it can only be, at most, 65536 strings. After all, imagine that both "Hi" and "Hello" compress down to '01 191'. So if I see '01 191', did you say Hi or did you say Hello? It's impossible to know.

If you severely reduce the amount of symbols that can be in the message, let's say down to only the capitals, space, and the digits, and that's it. No dots, no dashes, no underscores, no plusses, no question marks. That's only 26 + 1 + 10 = 37 characters. Let's knock off 5 more for convenience - we make the 'x' impossible, the 0 and 1 (just use the letter 'o' and 'l' I guess), q, and z. Now it's 32 characters. Which can be represented with exactly 5 bits. You have 16 of em, so you can now represent 3 letters with your 16 bits, with 1 bit left over.

But that's as far as it goes.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your feedback. I understand that it's impossible now. But, how would it be implemented if the user enters a long string? Is there any resources I can read up on to better learn about how to implement this?

Comment: You'd for example send 1 byte or 2 bytes representing the string size (if you send 1, your string can be no longer than 255 chars; if you sent 2, your limit is 65535), and then send that many bytes, e.g. with UTF-8 or US-ASCII or ISO-8859-1 encoding (these encodings turn strings into bytes). There aren't any other ways to do it, by its nature, strings are variable size.

Comment: I see, thank you so much! Your explanation gave me a good idea on how to work on it. Thank you again!